# How to callthe first float in a list in Python

Tags: python, call

In Python if I have numerous lines of data containing both strings and floats (sample below) which I have tokenized, how can I call the first float value in each line if this position is not constant? I eventually want to use this as a reference point for latter tokens. Thanks in advance.

F + FR > FR* + F + E               11.60    0     2  FR > FR*

F + FR > FR*** + F                 11.60    0  2382  FR > FR***

Comment: Please show the sample data

Comment: And what do you mean by "call"? Numbers are not callable (you can't say `123()`), do you want to store it in a variable, or print it?

Comment: Not worthy of a full answer, but generally after tokenizing you would convert the individual tokens into a parse tree, then you would traverse the parse tree to interpret the statement. Read up on PLY or ANTLR or any other lexer/parser type subsystems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `re` module. Just import it and look for digits with a `.` within them. For example,

```
import re
def findFloat(s): 
    return float( re.search('[0-9]+.[0-9]+', s).group() )
```

This finds the first occurrence of a group of numbers separated by a `.`